# Am I testing My repository the right way?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

I have a generic Repository like this:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity :class
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> SearchFor(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter);
    TEntity GetById(int id);
    void Insert(TEntity entity);
    void Delete(TEntity entity);
    void Update(TEntity entity);
}
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>  where TEntity: class
{
    private DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet; // put the entity specified in place of TEntity in d DbSet so i can query the entity e.g School Entity
    private NaijaSchoolsContext _naijaSchoolsContext;

    public GenericRepository(NaijaSchoolsContext context)
    {
        _naijaSchoolsContext = context;
        _dbSet = _naijaSchoolsContext.Set<TEntity>(); //return the entity specified in the TEntity and put it in DbSet
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> SearchFor(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter)
    {
        return _dbSet.Where(filter);
    }

    public TEntity GetById(int id)
    {
        return _dbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Remove(entity);
    }

    public void Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbSet.AddOrUpdate(entity);
    }
}
```

I also have a UoW like this:

```
public interface IUnitofWork : IDisposable
{
    void Save();
}

public class UnitofWork : IUnitofWork
{
    NaijaSchoolsContext naijaSchoolsContext = new NaijaSchoolsContext();
    private GenericRepository<School> schoolRepository;
    private bool isDisposed = false;

    public GenericRepository<School> SchoolRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (schoolRepository == null)
            {
                schoolRepository = new GenericRepository<School>(naijaSchoolsContext);
            }
            return schoolRepository;
        }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        naijaSchoolsContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!isDisposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                naijaSchoolsContext.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
       Dispose(true);
       GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

My test class looks like this:

```
 [TestFixture]
public class when_working_with_school_repository
{

}

public class and_saving_a_school : when_working_with_school_repository
{
    private School _returnedSchool;
    private School _school;
    private Mock<IRepository<School>> _repository;
    private Exception _result;


    [SetUp]
    private void SetUp()
    {
        _repository = new Mock<IRepository<School>>();
        _school = new School();
    }

    [Test]
    public void then_a_valid_school_should_be_saved()
    {
        _repository.Setup(s => s.Insert(_school));
        //_returnedSchool = _schoolRepository.Save(_school);
    }

    [Test]
    public void should_throw_an_exception_when_no_school_is_saved()
    {
        try
        {
            _repository.Setup(s => s.Insert(null));
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _result = exception;
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void should_notify_user_if_school_name_already_exists()
    {
        //bool exists = _schoolRepository.IsExist(_school.Name);
    }
}
```

My tests passes but my concern is that

1. Am I not supposed to mock the UnitOfWork class. When I tried mocking it, i couldn't get to the StudentRepository class. In using the code without tests, I would have to instantiate UoW to perform my actions, that is why i asked if am supposed to Mock my UoW. if am to Mock it how can i do that?
2. Please help me if my test is correct or I need to take another course of action.

Answer (score 1):

No, you are not. You are testing *mock*:

```
_repository = new Mock<IRepository<School>>();
```

You want to test *your code*, not others. Your generic repository simply delegates calls to `_dbSet`. And that's what you want to test - that calls are delegated (this is sort of wrapper-functionality).

How to do that? You need abstraction over `DbSet<T>` and this is the object you mock in test. All your tests will look similar:

```
var dbSetMock = new Mock<DbSet<School>>();
var context = new Mock<Context>();
var repository = new GenericRepository<School>(dbSetMock, context);

repository.FindBy(arg);

dbSetMock.Verify(d => d.FindBy(arg));
```

This requires abstraction over both `DbSet` and your custom context to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're better of mocking the IRepository. But, your test will pass because your not asserting for anything.

I think you need to setup your your mock inorder to get the desired result. Here is a modified example:

```
[Test]
public void then_a_valid_school_should_be_saved()
{
    var _school = new School { .... };
    var expected = _school.Id;
    _repository.Setup(s => s.Insert(_school));
    _repository.Setup(s => s.GetById(_school.Id)).Returns(_school);;

    _repository.Insert(_school);
    var actual = _repository.GetById(_school.Id);

    Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
}
```

That should do it. To make the test fail try putting a different Id for the expected result and verify that it works. You can use that to improve upon your other test.